# How to add SecureSocial to Play 2.x project with build.sbt (not Build.scala)

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm pretty new to Play! 2.x and sbt, and to add to the confusion, the documentation they have on dependencies is different from how they've done the example projects in Activator. In particular, I'm working with the `hello-play` template project.

There is no `Build.scala` file, but there is a `build.sbt` file.  I'm trying to add the SecureSocial module following the [Installation](http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html) document.

The `build.sbt` file looks as follows:

```
name := """hello-play"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += "sbt-plugin-snapshots" at "http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaCore,  // The core Java API
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1",
  "securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.2"
)

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

At compile time, it shows that it tried using the resolver I gave, but no luck:

```
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-snapshots: tried
[warn] http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/securesocial/securesocial_2.10/2.1.2/securesocial_2.10-2.1.2.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: securesocial#securesocial_2.10;2.1.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: securesocial#securesocial_2.10;2.1.2: not found
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Play Framework 2.2 switched the default build definition from `Build.scala` to `build.sbt` and SecureSocial just hasn't updated their docs yet.  However you almost got it.  Just change your `resolvers` line to:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I must have been looking at Play documentation that wasn't the latest.